# Are Query-Specific DbExecutionStrategies possible in EF6?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, entity-framework-6

**Update**: The issue was I was evaluating which execution strategy to use in the constructor rather than leaving it in the lambda.  In other words, I had this inside the constructor of MyConfiguration...

```
var strategy = SuspendExecutionStrategy 
    ? (IDbExecutionStrategy)new DefaultExecutionStrategy()
    : new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
this.SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => strategy);
```

instead of having that evaluation *inside* the lambda.

**Original Question:**
Is there any way in Entity Framework 6.0 to have some queries on a DbContext use one execution strategy and others use a different one?  I see the below example in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-resiliency/retry-logic).

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        this.SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => SuspendExecutionStrategy
          ? (IDbExecutionStrategy)new DefaultExecutionStrategy()
          : new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
    }

    public static bool SuspendExecutionStrategy
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool?)CallContext.LogicalGetData("SuspendExecutionStrategy")  false;
        }
        set
        {
            CallContext.LogicalSetData("SuspendExecutionStrategy", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, in my testing, it looks like if I create multiple instances of my *DbContext* class, there's only a single call to *DbConfiguration's* constructor with that singleton configuration object getting shared between the context objects.  So while I could set this at startup with *SuspendExecutionStrategy*, I couldn't change it at runtime.  I imagine later calls to *SetExecutionStrategy*() could change it, but I have multiple threads and would like some to be using one *DbExecutionStrategy* and others to be using a different one (specifically for retryable vs non-retryable queries).

Is there some setting somewhere that could change *DbConfiguration* to not be a singleton for the class and instead be specific to a particular instance of *DbContext*?  Or am I misunderstanding something entirely?

Ideally, I'd love to be able to do something like...

```
using(var repo = new MyDbContext()){
    repo.SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
    // do some queries to my repository
}
```

in one thread and then in another, have

```
using(var repo = new MyDbContext()){
    repo.SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => (IDbExecutionStrategy)new DefaultExecutionStrategy());
    // do some queries to my repository
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code (that is not working) where you set `SuspendExecutionStrategy` to true?

Comment: It's not an issue with setting SuspendExecutionStrategy.  That gets set just fine. 
The issue is that it's not read later.  SuspendExecutionStrategy is only read from in DbConfiguration's constructor in Microsoft's example.  In my own code, I've found with breakpoints that even if you create multiple DbContext instances, they all share the same DbConfiguration instance as if it's an under-the-hood singleton.  Since I would like to use multiple DbExecutionStrategies at the same time (one with retries, one without), I seem to need multiple simultaneous configuration instances of the same class.

Comment: Well sure the can share the same instance, but I assume the func that is passed to the `SetExecutionStrategy` is executed upon each db call. So, the Boolean should be read each time upon the invocation of the func. Otherwise it wouldn't be useful to have a func argument in the first place.

Comment: Ahh...  That was the issue.  I was evaluating which one to use outside the lambda and passing in that value rather than the function.  Thank you!

Comment: You could add it as an answer so that others who have same problem could get it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was evaluating which execution strategy to use in the constructor rather than leaving it in the lambda. In other words, I had this inside the constructor of MyConfiguration...

```
var strategy = SuspendExecutionStrategy 
    ? (IDbExecutionStrategy)new DefaultExecutionStrategy()
    : new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
this.SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => strategy);
```

instead of having that evaluation *inside* the lambda.  It's a subtle difference, but it changes when it's actually evaluated (on construction vs on-use).